# lightdm can't start

Tags: lightdm

I tried to use lightdm in WSL2 ubuntu, however it doesn't work. I tried reinstall lightdm and polkit. It seems like something about dbus is wrong.

ubuntu:22.04.1 GUI:GNOME

```
ding@LAPTOP-V70877ES:~$ sudo service lightdm start
 * Starting X display manager lightdm                                                                                   [+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.30.0, UID=0 PID=4836
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module local
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ?gio-vfs?
[+0.01s] WARNING: Failed to get list of logind seats: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.login1: Permission denied
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Launching X Server
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching process 4844: /bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.01s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.01s] WARNING: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program org.freedesktop.Accounts: Permission denied
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading user config from /etc/lightdm/users.conf
[+0.01s] WARNING: Failed to read password database: No such file or directory
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User ding added
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Process 4844 terminated with signal 6
[+0.03s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.03s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping; greeter display server failed to start
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try  getting in to grub terminal at the start up
then alt ctl alt f2 may be to login as root
user then password
if you get that far
try typing this  sudo -i is a good command it gives root privileges
and then  type this systemctl start lightdm

another would be dpkg--reconfigure-lightdm or you could see if you have problem with dpkg packages
by typing dkgp --audit
to exit  out of root
type exit
world pandemic treaty agreement 2024